# ¿Por qué Visual Studio 2015 no puede compilar un archivo exe (ucrtbased.dll)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, exe

Tengo instalado Visual Studio 2015 y creé un proyecto, pero cuando lo mando a correr me sale este mensaje:

> "The program can't start because ucrtbased.dll is missing from your
>   computer."

**¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?**

Comment: Puede solucionar su problema reinstalando visual studio :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conozco dos opciones

1. Reinstalar
2. Copiar el archivo a este path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\ucrt\ucrtbased.dll`  32 Bits `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\ucrt\ucrtbased.dll` 64 bits

Esto en Windows 10, no he instalado 2015 en versiones anteriores, el archivo puede ser descargado de una librería de dll´s online, pero debe ser una segura, por aquello de los virus.